# ZipList Monoid haskell

Tags: haskell, monoids

The default monoid for lists in the GHC Prelude is concatenation.

`[1,2,3] <> [4,5,6]` becomes `[1,2,3] ++ [4,5,6]` and thus `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

I want to write a ZipList Monoid instance that behaves like this:

```
[
  1 <> 4
, 2 <> 5
, 3 <> 6
]
```

The result is `[5,7,9]` assuming I am using the sum monoid.
Note this behaves like `zipWith (+)`

Potentially it would behave like this:

```
[
  Sum 1 <> Sum 4
, Sum 2 <> Sum 5
, Sum 3 <> Sum 6
]
```

I need to create a newtype around the `ZipList` newtype and the `Sum` newtype in order to create an instance for `Monoid`, `Arbitrary`, and `EqProp`. 
Thus avoiding orphan instances.
This is how both the `ZipList` and the `Sum` looks like in the `Prelude`:

```
newtype ZipList a = ZipList { getZipList :: [a] }
newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }
```

This is how my newtype `MyZipList` looks: Does it look right?

```
newtype MyZipList a =
  MyZipList (ZipList [a])
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (MyZipList a) where
  mempty = MyZipList (ZipList [])

  mappend (MyZipList z) (MyZipList z') =
    MyZipList $ liftA2 mappend z z'

instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (MyZipList a) where
  arbitrary = MyZipList <$> arbitrary

instance Eq a => EqProp (MyZipList a) where
  (=-=) = eq
```

This is how my newtype`MySum` looks like:
Does this look right?

```
newtype MySum a =
  MySum (Sum a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

 instance (Num a, Monoid a) => Monoid (MySum a) where
   mempty = MySum mempty

   mappend (MySum s) (MySum s') = MySum $ s <> s'

 instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (MySum a) where
   arbitrary = MySum <$> arbitrary
```

I would like assistance in finding out where I went wrong.

Comment: But `x <> mempty == mempty <> x == x` (that is one of the properties of a monoid), in your case `mempty <> x == mempty`. I think in case of a `ZipList`, the `mappend` should be equal to an infinite list of `mempty`s (of the `a` type).

Comment: Why do you create a new newtype instead of just adding a Monoid instance for `ZipList a`?

Comment: @DominiqueDevriese "I need to create a newtype ... *Thus avoiding orphan instances.*"

Comment: If your goal was for `MySum` to behave exactly like `Sum` then that at least looks right. Although I'm not sure why you're wrapping `Sum` and `ZipList` if you're going to re-implement their behaviour anyway - you might as well just build `MySum` and `MyZipList` directly.

That being said, you said you want assistance but you didn't actually say what your problem was. You explained pretty well what you actually did, but your question is missing a description of what's actually going wrong.

Answer (score 10):

First note that `ZipList`’s `Applicative` instance already has the zippy behaviour you want.

```
ghci> liftA2 (<>) (Sum <$> ZipList [1,2,3]) (Sum <$> ZipList [4,5,6]) :: ZipList Int
ZipList [Sum 5, Sum 7, Sum 9]
```

Then use the fact that any `Applicative` gives rise to a `Monoid` by lifting the monoidal behaviour of its contents through the monoidal functor itself. The plan is to abstract the `liftA2 (<>)` pattern from the expression I wrote above.

```
newtype Ap f a = Ap { getAp :: f a }
instance (Applicative f, Monoid a) => Monoid (Ap f a) where
    mempty = Ap $ pure mempty
    Ap xs `mappend` Ap ys = Ap $ liftA2 mappend xs ys
```

(As far as I know this `newtype` is missing from `base`, which seems like an oversight to me, though there may be a good reason for it. In fact, I’d argue that `ZipList` should have a zippy `Monoid` instance out of the box, but, alas, it doesn’t.)

Your desired `Monoid` is then just `Ap ZipList (Sum Int)`. This is equivalent to the `MyZipList` `Monoid` you wrote by hand (except for the mistake in your `mempty` - it should be `MyZipList $ ZipList $ repeat mempty`), but composing it out of reusable `newtype`s like this is less ad-hoc and requires less boilerplate.

Comment: Is there a way to use `Compose` here?

Comment: @chepner I guess `Ap f = Compose f Identity`, but sadly [`Compose` doesn't have the `Monoid` instance we'd want either](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson How would you implement an `Arbitrary (Ap f a)` for `quickBatch` testing?  I've tried `instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Ap f a) where arbitrary = liftA2 (<>) Ap arbitrary arbitrary` and a few other variations, but none worked..

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson You can also check out what I'm trying to do at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716919/haskell-quickbatch-testing-ziplist-monoid-at-mconcat-results-in-stack-overflow.

Comment: You'd wanna reuse `ZipList`'s `Arbitrary`, right? `instance Arbitrary (f a) => Arbitrary (Ap f a) where arbitrary = Ap arbitrary`

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thanks!  I tried that, but got this error:  `Couldn't match expected type ‘Test.QuickCheck.Gen.Gen (Ap f a)’ with actual type ‘Ap Test.QuickCheck.Gen.Gen a0’ In the expression: Ap arbitrary`

Comment: `arbitrary = Ap <$> arbitrary`, my mistake

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thanks, I've just posted my attempt at quickBatch.  Could you help with the `EqProp (Ap f a)`?  Is my `quickBatch $ monoid app` going in the right direction?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I've posted my attempt with quickBatch at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752398/haskell-quickbatch-testing-applicative-monoid-ziplist.  Hope you can help with that.

Comment: @Dharman Sorry for my mis-post here.  I've deleted the post.

Comment: Since you wrote this, `Ap` has been added to `Data.Monoid` (in `base-4.12.0.0`).

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Sorry, I'm now wondering why `arbitrary = Ap <$> arbitrary` works, but `arbitrary = Ap arbitrary` doesn't.. could you or @dfeuer help explain?