# Haskell quickBatch testing: Applicative Monoid ZipList

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do a `quickBatch` test on the solution provided at [ZipList Monoid haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130388/ziplist-monoid-haskell).  I'll need some advice as to how to continue from here or should I try something else for `EqProp (Ap f a)`?  How do I go about deriving a solution for this?

```
newtype Ap f a = Ap { getAp :: f a }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
instance (Applicative f, Semigroup a) =>
  Semigroup (Ap f a) where
    Ap xs <> Ap ys = 
      Ap $ liftA2 (<>) xs ys
instance (Applicative f, Monoid a) => 
  Monoid (Ap f a) where
    mempty = Ap $ pure mempty
    Ap xs `mappend` Ap ys = 
      Ap $ liftA2 mappend xs ys
app :: Ap ZipList (Sum Int)
app = Ap (ZipList [1,2 :: Sum Int])
test :: Ap ZipList (Sum Int)
test = app <> app
instance Arbitrary (f a) =>
  Arbitrary (Ap f a) where
    arbitrary = Ap <$> arbitrary  
instance Eq a => EqProp (Ap f a) where
  xs =-= ys = xs' `eq` ys' where 
    xs' = 
      let (Ap l) = xs
        in take 3000 l
    ys' = 
      let (Ap l) = ys
        in take 3000 l
main :: IO ()
main = do
  quickBatch $ monoid app
```

There are 2 similar error messages for this code, each for the 2 lines:
`in take 3000 l`

Error message:

```
Couldn't match type ‘f’ with ‘[]’
‘f’ is a rigid type variable bound by
the instance declaration at Line of Code
Expected type: [a]
Actual type: f a
In the second argument of ‘take’, namely ‘l’
In the expression: take 3000 l
```

Comment: Just... don't call `take`? Why is that in there anyway? (In fact you can probably shorten it even further to just `(=-=) = eq`.)

Comment: Please delete the image of your error message and instead copy and paste the actual text of the message. Images of text are inaccessible to visually impaired users and useless for searching.

Comment: @DanielWagner, the `take` is presumably to avoid infinite loops checking, e.g., `mempty <> mempty = mempty`.

Comment: @dfeuer Aaaah, yeah, that's... unfortunate.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I guess it's actually *just* for `mempty <> mempty = mempty`. So the cutoff could be limited to pairs of lists whose first `n` elements are all `mempty`. But that starts to get a bit silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you say

```
instance Eq a => EqProp (Ap f a)
```

but then in the instance you use `take`, which works only for lists and not arbitrary type constructors `f`. For testing purposes, it would be reasonable to just limit the instance with either

```
instance Eq a => EqProp (Ap ZipList a)
```

or

```
instance (Eq a, f ~ ZipList) => EqProp (Ap f a)
```

You'll still need to unwrap the `ZipList`s. Either of these will require additional language extensions; just do what the error messages say. Outside of testing, it's usually better practice to use a newtype wrapper: something like

```
{-# language GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, DeriveTraversable #-}
newtype MonZipList a = MonZipList (Ap ZipList a)
  deriving (Applicative, Alternative, Semigroup
    , Monoid, Functor, Foldable, Traversable, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried: `instance Eq a => EqProp (Ap ZipList a) where ..`, but I got another error message at the same lines of code: `Couldn't match expected type ‘[a1]’ with actual type ‘ZipList a’ In the second argument of ‘take’, namely ‘l’ In the expression: take 3000 l`.

Comment: @maxloo, right, you have to unwrap the `ZipList`, not just the `Ap`.

Comment: @maxloo, `getZipList . getAp` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that works!  Could I also find out how MonZipList is used?

Comment: @maxloo huh? That's rather vague. What do you still not understand?

Comment: I do not quite understand how MonZipList is used.  Does that mean I should declare instead something like: `newtype Ap f a = Ap { getAp :: f a } deriving (Eq, Show, Semigroup, Monoid, Functor, Applicative)`?

Comment: @maxloo, the idea is that instead of using `Ap ZipList` directly for tests, you can write a wrapper newtype carrying that, give that wrapper an `EqProp` instance, and derive everything else you need. It's probably overkill in practice for a test suite, but it avoids the potential problems of having an orphan instance.

Comment: Ok, I've tried: `newtype MonZipList a = MonZipList (Ap ZipList a) deriving (Applicative, Semigroup, Monoid, Functor, Eq, Show)`, but got 2 similar errors for Applicative and Functor: `No instance for (Applicative (Ap ZipList)) arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration.  Possible fix: use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration, so you can specify the instance context yourself.`  But when I tried `deriving instance (Applicative, Semigroup, Monoid, Functor, Eq, Show)`, I get the error `parse error on input ‘instance’`.  So, what should I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227424/discussion-between-maxloo-and-dfeuer).

Comment: I've posted my reply in the chat, hope to hear from you..