# Haskell quickBatch testing: newtype wrapper for Ap ZipList

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do a wrapper newtype for my `Ap ZipList` based on the advice given at [Haskell quickBatch testing: Applicative Monoid ZipList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752398/haskell-quickbatch-testing-applicative-monoid-ziplist).  My version of GHC is 8.8.4 and I compile using stack.  My full code:

```
newtype Ap f a = Ap { getAp :: f a }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
instance (Applicative f, Semigroup a) =>
  Semigroup (Ap f a) where
    Ap xs <> Ap ys = 
      Ap $ liftA2 (<>) xs ys
instance (Applicative f, Monoid a) => 
  Monoid (Ap f a) where
    mempty = Ap $ pure mempty
    Ap xs `mappend` Ap ys = 
      Ap $ liftA2 mappend xs ys
app :: Ap ZipList (Sum Int)
app = Ap (ZipList [1,2 :: Sum Int])
test :: Ap ZipList (Sum Int)
test = app <> app
instance Arbitrary (f a) =>
  Arbitrary (Ap f a) where
    arbitrary = Ap <$> arbitrary  
instance Eq a => EqProp (Ap ZipList a) where
  xs =-= ys = xs' `eq` ys' where 
    xs' = 
      let (Ap (ZipList l)) = xs
        in take 3000 l
    ys' = 
      let l = (getZipList . getAp) ys
        in take 3000 l

newtype MonZipList a = 
  MonZipList (Ap ZipList a)
  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid, Eq, Show)
deriving instance Functor f => 
  Functor (Ap f)
deriving instance Applicative f => 
  Applicative (Ap f)
monapp :: MonZipList (Sum Int)
monapp = MonZipList app
instance Arbitrary a =>
  Arbitrary (MonZipList a) where
    arbitrary = MonZipList <$> arbitrary
instance Eq a => EqProp (MonZipList a) where
  (=-=) = eq

main :: IO ()
main = do 
  quickBatch $ monoid app
  quickBatch $ monoid monapp
  quickBatch $ functor monapp
  quickBatch $ applicative monapp
```

The basic `quickBatch $ monoid app` tests run well without problems.

The problems I face are that when I run `quickBatch $ monoid monapp`, the monoid tests hangs at the mconcat test and could not be stopped.  I had to close my WSL Bash in order to stop it from running.

When I tried `quickBatch $ functor monapp` or `quickBatch $ applicative monapp`, errors were thrown, thereby making the effectiveness of the wrapper newtype questionable:
Couldn't match type ‘Sum Int’ with ‘(a0, b0, c0)’
Expected type: MonZipList (a0, b0, c0)
Actual type: MonZipList (Sum Int)
In the first argument of ‘functor’, namely ‘monapp’

Are there any solutions to these newtype wrapper problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're running into two separate problems, neither of which is really the result of using a newtype wrapper.

First, `ZipList` has infinite lists under the hood in the case of `mempty`, which is probably why your `monoid monapp` test is hanging.  It looks like you're taking care of this in your `EqProp (Ap ZipList a)` instance, but not in your `EqProp (MonZipList a)` instance.  That's a little strange.  Perhaps what you meant to do was to remove the `EqProp (Ap ZipList a)` instance altogether and *just* have the `EqProp (MonZipList a)` instance, but use the code from the `EqProp (Ap ZipList a)` instance?  Something like:

```hs
instance Eq a => EqProp (MonZipList a) where
  MonZipList (Ap (ZipList xs)) =-= MonZipList (Ap (ZipList ys)) = 
    take 3000 xs `eq` take 3000 ys
```

As for `functor monapp`, the types don't line up at all.  For `functor` and `applicative`, you need to provide 3 arbitrary types for the tests to use.

You may not know this, but the actual *value* you provide to, e.g., `functor` is irrelevant -- it's only interested in the types.  Personally, I find it easier to just provide the types as arguments for these functions directly, as in:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
main = do 
  quickBatch $ monoid @(MonZipList (Sum Int)) undefined
  quickBatch $ functor @MonZipList @Int @Bool @Char undefined
  quickBatch $ applicative @MonZipList @String @Int @Char undefined
```

Now it becomes clear what's going on: for the `functor` tests, use the `MonZipList` functor along with arbitrary (and coarbitrary) values from the types `Int`, `Bool`, and `Char` for testing.  You can feel free to change those types or to run multiple `functor` tests if you really want to test it with other types too.

Comment: I do have a related question, which was first raised at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716919/haskell-quickbatch-testing-ziplist-monoid-at-mconcat-results-in-stack-overflow, if ZipList has infinite lists for mempty, why is it that the program hangs at the mconcat test for monoid?  Shouldn't it also hang at the mappend test for monoid?

Comment: I posted an [answer to this over on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65764731/14802384)