# Haskell quickBatch: Ap applicative monoid

Tags: haskell

Based on the suggestion provided at [ZipList Monoid haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130388/ziplist-monoid-haskell), I have created this code which works:

```
newtype Ap f a = Ap { getAp :: f a }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
instance (Applicative f, Semigroup a) =>
  Semigroup (Ap f a) where
    Ap xs <> Ap ys = 
      Ap $ liftA2 (<>) xs ys
instance (Applicative f, Monoid a) => 
  Monoid (Ap f a) where
    mempty = Ap $ pure mempty
    Ap xs `mappend` Ap ys = 
      Ap $ liftA2 mappend xs ys
app :: Ap ZipList (Sum Int)
app = Ap (ZipList [1,2 :: Sum Int])
instance Arbitrary (f a) =>
  Arbitrary (Ap f a) where
    arbitrary = Ap <$> arbitrary 
instance Eq a => EqProp (Ap ZipList a) where
  xs =-= ys = xs' `eq` ys' where 
    xs' = 
      let (Ap (ZipList l)) = xs
        in take 3000 l
    ys' = 
      let l = (getZipList . getAp) ys
        in take 3000 l
main :: IO ()
main = do
  quickBatch $ monoid app
```

However, I do not fully understand how the code works.  Why is it `mempty = Ap $ pure mempty`?  How is this equation calculated or derived?  Why is it `Ap xs 'mappend' Ap ys`?  I would have thought that since it is `Monoid (Ap f a)`, it should be `Ap f xs 'mappend' Ap f ys`?

And why is it that when the quickBatch monoid tests are run on Ap, it doesn't result in stackoverflow at the mconcat test as seen at [Haskell quickBatch: Testing ZipList Monoid at mconcat results in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716919/haskell-quickbatch-testing-ziplist-monoid-at-mconcat-results-in-stack-overflow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it `mempty = Ap $ pure mempty`?  How is this equation calculated or derived?  Why is it `Ap xs 'mappend' Ap ys`?  I would have thought that since it is `Monoid (Ap f a)`, it should be `Ap f xs 'mappend' Ap f ys`?

In order to answer these questions, it will be important to take a careful look at the definition of `Ap` itself:

```hs
newtype Ap f a = Ap { getAp :: f a }
```

This declaration introduces both a new type `Ap` and a new constructor `Ap`—they have the same name but they are definitely different entities.

The type `Ap` has kind `(Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type`, which is to say that it takes two arguments: `f`, which itself is a function on types, and `a`, which is just a type.  We can use the type `Ap` in type signatures, when we write things like `app :: Ap ZipList (Sum Int)` or in class instances like `instance Eq a => EqProp (Ap ZipList a)`.

The constructor `Ap` has type `f a -> Ap f a` (note the use of the type version of `Ap` here!).  This constructor takes *one* argument, a value of type `f a`, in order to produce a value of type `Ap f a`.  So, for instance, you can write:

```hs
t1 :: Ap Maybe Int
t1 = Ap (Just 3)

t2 :: Ap [] Bool
t2 = Ap [True, False]

t3 :: Ap ZipList Int
t3 = Ap (ZipList [1,2,3])
```

Notice that in every case, the *type* `Ap` takes two arguments, but the constructor `Ap` takes one argument.

Now, let's consider how to write the `Monoid` instance for `Ap f a`.  Let's recall the `Monoid` class:

```hs
class Semigroup a => Monoid a where
  mempty  :: a
  mappend :: a -> a -> a
```

So, for `instance (Applicative f, Monoid a) => Monoid (Ap f a)`, we'll need `mempty :: Ap f a` and `mappend :: Ap f a -> Ap f a -> Ap f a`.  How can we write `mempty`?  Well, first off, we need a value of type `Ap f a`, and the only way we've seen so far for how to make one is with the `Ap` constructor.  Recalling the `Ap` constructor, that means we need a value of type `f a` that we can feed to it.  How can we produce one of those?  Fortunately, we know `Monoid a`, so we have access to `mempty :: a`, and we know `Applicative f`, so we have access to `pure :: forall x. x -> f x`.  Sticking these two together, we can make a value `pure mempty :: f a`.  All that's left is to provide that to the `Ap` constructor:

```hs
  mempty = Ap $ pure mempty
```

Next, we need to define `mappend`.  We're given two values of type `Ap f a`, which means they must be of the form `Ap x` for some values `x` (remember that the `Ap` in `Ap x` here is the constructor, not the type).  So, we begin by pattern matching:

```hs
  Ap xs `mappend` Ap ys = ...
```

What types do `xs` and `ys` have?  Well, `Ap xs :: Ap f a`, and `Ap :: f a -> Ap f a`, so `xs, ys :: f a`.  We need to somehow combine these two values of type `f a` into a single value of type `f a`, and then we can use the `Ap` constructor to wrap it up for output.  We can do this with `liftA2 mappend xs ys`.  This gives us:

```hs
  Ap xs `mappend` Ap ys = Ap $ liftA2 mappend xs ys
```

As a note here, check out how it wouldn't make sense to write something like:

```hs
  Ap f xs `mappend` Ap g ys` = -- pattern error!
```

because we'd be mixing up the type `Ap`, which takes two arguments, with the constructor `Ap`, which takes only one.

---

> And why is it that when the quickBatch monoid tests are run on Ap, it doesn't result in stackoverflow at the mconcat test

The stack overflow is the result of trying to compare two infinite lists for equality.  GHC will just keep checking each element looking for either the end of the list or for two elements that aren't equal, and since the lists are infinitely long, the program won't terminate (or will run out of memory).

However, in your definition of `EqProp` for `Ap ZipList a`, you're basically saying that it's okay to only check the first 3000 elements of a list for equality.  So, even if infinite lists are encountered, as long as the first 3000 elements are equal, we can just go ahead and assume that the lists are equal.

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact *the only possible* definition (except ⊥).

- Knowing nothing more about the monoid, the only expressions you can write are of the form `mempty <> mempty <> ... <> mempty`, which is just `mempty` by monoid laws.
- Knowing nothing more about the applicative, only expressions you can write are of the form `f <$> pure y <*> pure z <*> ...`, which is the same as `pure $ f y z ...` where `f` is some n-ary function on the monoid – which again can only have the form `\y' z' ... -> y' <> mempty <> ... <> z' <> mempty`, and also `y` and `z` can only be `mempty`.

So, whatever expression you could possibly write, it'll always be identical to `pure mempty`, provided the monoid and applicative you put in are law-abiding.

Comment: Thanks, when you say `mempty <> mempty <> mempty <> mempty <> ...`, do you mean `mempty = Ap $ pure mempty` has a definition similar to the definition of `mempty = pure mempty` as described in the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716919/haskell-quickbatch-testing-ziplist-monoid-at-mconcat-results-in-stack-overflow?

Comment: How does the use of `Ap` change `pure mempty`?  Why is it that if I run quickBatch monoid tests on Ap ZipList, it will not hang at the monoid mconcat test?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking. — For `ZipList` it _would_ be possible to write other definitions of `mempty`, because you do know something about the applicative there, so the argument wouldn't hold up then. But here it does, because you're dealing with _some opaque_ `Applicative f`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the confusion, but I've updated my post again because I realised I really don't understand Ap's definition very well..

Comment: For `mempty = Ap $ pure mempty`, why is it not `mempty = Ap f $ pure mempty` or `mempty = Ap f <$> pure mempty` or simply `mempty = pure mempty`?  What do you mean by opaque `Applicative f`?

Comment: `Ap f $ ...` is not something you can write, because `f` is a type-level variable, you can't put it in a value constructor. (Remember that `Ap` means two different things in your code: it's the name of both the _type constructor_ `Ap :: (Type->Type) -> Type -> Type` and the _value constructor_ `Ap :: f a -> Ap f a`.) — But `f` _is_ a variable, meaning you can't just pull values out of thin air (like you could, for example, if you knew you're dealing with the list applicative: there you could always just write an empty list). You can only generate `f a` values by using `pure` and `<$>`.